# How to check if a certain port is open and unused?

Tags: linux

I want to install webserver-apache on a Linux platform which uses port no.80 but I am not sure whether is port is open or not, and is being used by some other application or not.

1. Output of `grep 80 /etc/services` is:

```
http  80/tcp  www www-http   #World Wide web Http
http  80/udp  www www-http   #Hypertext transfer protocol
```

2. `netstat -an | grep 80 | more`:

It gives some IP's one of which is

```
IP:80 TIME_WAIT
```

Could you please help and tell how can i find out if port 80 is open and unused so that I can start installation.

Comment: For what it's worth, `/etc/services` is completely static. Grepping it can tell you if a port is officially designated by IANA or some such, but does not tell whether or not it's in local use.

Answer (score 22):

```
sudo netstat -anp | grep ':80 '
```

That should give you pid & name of the process that holds port 80

Answer (score 14):

This can be achieved using the `nc` command as follows:

`# nc -z IP PORT`

It will return TRUE if the port is already in use, or FALSE is it  (i.e, available not listening currently).

I don't recommend `lsof` or `netstat` method as it first try to scan all running PIDs to get all bounded ports:

````
# time lsof -i:8888
real    0m1.194s
user    0m0.137s
sys 0m1.056s```

# time nc -z 127.0.0.1 8888
real    0m0.014s
user    0m0.011s
sys 0m0.004s
````

Here 8888 is an unused port. The `nc` command is ~85 times faster in the above example.

#### Eg 1:

```
$ nc -z 127.0.0.1 80 && echo "IN USE" || echo "FREE"
IN USE

$ nc -z 127.0.0.1 81 && echo "IN USE" || echo "FREE"
FREE
```

#### Eg 2:

If you are trying with a remote IP, it is better to add a timeout to auto-exit if it is not accepting connection for the specified time.

`$ nc -w 2 -z 216.58.196.174 81`

Its Google's IP which is not used, so it will timeout after trying for 2 seconds.

Comment: This also works greatly when running inside the Docker image that uses host network. Inside the image, lsof incorrectly reports the port is not in use when it actually is.

Comment: The traditional version of `nc` does not include the `-z` option. See [the differences between traditional and openbsd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346869/what-are-the-differences-between-netcat-traditional-and-netcat-openbsd).

Answer (score 7):

```
netstat -tln | tail -n +3 | awk '{ print $4 }'
```

This one displays bind addresses of TCP listening endpoints. All other endpoints are free;
Also if on Unix and you are not root, then you can't bind to a 'privileged' port number (port number lower than 1024).

Explained in more details:

- `netstat -tln`   - all listening tcp ports
- `tail -n +3`  - cut off the header of netstat command
- `awk '{ print $4 }'`  - print the fourth column that consists of [ip]:[port]

For the general case you still need to care to cut out all irrelevant interfaces;
a listening address 0.0.0.0 is listening on all network cards, if there is an IP address then that's the specific IP of the network card/network interface.

Answer (score 5):

Try piping lsof into grep and searching for a port number:

```
lsof|grep <port>
```

If nothing shows up that means the port is not in use

You can kill a process on a specific port using

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

Where pid is the process id obtained from the first command.

Comment: Hey Dillon: It is giving me the output...some crond, httpd....etc with some path on thr right side like /sbin/klogd...lots like that

Comment: The reason why you're getting a lot of results is because you're using port 80. There are many other processes that are running on that port.

Comment: oh okay, so that means I can not use port 80 for Apache !! :(  anyways thanks for your help

Comment: Don't use `kill -9` on an unfamiliar program! http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#kill

Comment: @tripleee you're absolutely right. I was just stated that if you want you can.

Comment: You can certainly kill processes with `kill` but you should not use signal 9 unless you know that regular signals (primarily 15 and 2) don't work. See the link for more.

Comment: @DillonBenson I have haproxy running on a server at port 9019. This command didn't give any output. Ubuntu 140.4 Aws EC2 instance.

Answer (score 5):

As part of a script you would probably want to use something like this:

```
resp=`netstat -tunl | grep ":80 "`
if [ -z "$resp" ]; then
    echo "80 Port is free"
else
    echo "80 Port is not free"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is command which you need to kill

```
netstat -tulpno | grep ':80'
```

Answer (score 0):

The below command *with output* means  **the port is open** and *without output* means **it's not open**

```
 sudo fuser -i 80/tcp
```

And you can kill the listening process with this command:

```
sudo fuser -k 80/tcp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
#this function will exist from bash script if any of the port in argument list is in used 
function seek_port()  {
for i in $@
do
 echo $i
 netstat -nat | grep LISTEN | grep -E "\b:$i\b"
 if [ $? -eq 0 ]
 then
   echo "TCP port $i opened"
   exit 0
 fi
done
}
#calling function
seek_port 80 443
```

Answer (score -1):

```
grep  '443' /etc/httpd/conf.d/*
```